# Model binder not binding an int array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm posting some form data through ajax to my server. I also grab a some Id's from an array in memory and add it to the form data:

```
var postData = $('#frmMoveToNewPackage').serializeArray();

postData.push({
    name: 'DocumentIds',
    value: _checkboxList.getAllChecked()
});

$.post('@Url.Action("MoveToNewPackage")', postData);
```

My model is this:

```
public class MoveToNewPackageModel
{
    [Required]
    public int OldPackageID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Package NewPackage { get; set; }

    public List<string> DocumentIds { get; set; } 
}
```

This works. However technically the list of DocumentIds should be a `List<int>`. If I change the type in my modal, and change the post data:

```
postData.push({
    name: 'DocumentIds',
    value: _checkboxList.getAllChecked().map(function(item) { return parseInt(item);});
});
```

Then my `DocumentIds` is an empty (but not null) list of ints. I've looked at the data being posted and it's a valid int array.

EDIT: Above is wrong. It was not correctly binding the list of strings. It was just jamming everything into the first item of the string array.

Comment: What does the HTTP request parameter list look like? (The browser developer tools will tell you.) HTTP parameters are always strings.

Comment: Form data from Chrome's Header tab: `DocumentIds:34382,34383` Seems a little off that there are no brackets or anything.

Comment: Oh wait, I was wrong in saying it's working as a list of strings. It's putting the entire content as the first item! I'll update the question.

Comment: Right, so something (jQuery? depends on how you're doing the XHR) is simply coercing the array to a string. The way that arrays are posted usually involves either repeating the same parameter name for each array entry, or else using parameter names with array-like index suffixes. It depends on the server environment which way works.

Comment: I think I'll map the array to a new object with a new name `DocumentIds[i]` for each index. It will be a little ugly but it will work.

Comment: @Dave Please do not delete [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902055/why-does-this-form-submit-with-no-named-parameters/36902573) especially with up-votes. If you found a solution, you can answer own question and mark it as Answer. By doing so, it will help others who look for the same answer.